# How to "stream" json from server to client using javascript

Tags: ajax, json

I'm familiar enough with Ajax and JSON that I can send a request and get a parse a JSON request. Ideally I'd like to receive multiple response to periodically update a progress bar. This way clients can have a positive feedback.

I've heard of JSON streams but have not found a good resource on how to implement this. Does anyone know of a good resource or how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is just yet another format of data going over the HTTP protocol (like text, html, pdf, etc). You are probably referring to [cometd](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/).

This allows you to open a persistent connection and push data from the server to the client (ie stream it). Any format is valid to push, the client just needs to understand it.

Comment: Well of course, but how to stream individual JSON fragments correctly?

Comment: yea... my answer wasn't my best. But basically my experience is that there isn't a standard here. The way I've seen it happen is that you define a delimeter. Using a newline works pretty well. As a result the client just "readlines" the stream. Each line is assumed to be a full json object/payload that is consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a technique called [page streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).

Basically you write `<script>some js</script>` entries into the persistent connection and flush them into the network interface. As browser receives that, it will parse and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function doSomething() {
    // do something here...
   }
   setInterval('doSomething()',10000);
<script>
```

That will call a function every 10 seconds.  So you can poll the server every 10 seconds (or 1 second) to get a response on the status of whatever event you're trying to track.  Simply put your AJAX call inside that function and it'll send.

Comment: This is not streaming.

Comment: When this answer was written, 7 years ago, WebSockets were not a thing, and the only true streaming option was Flash. Since "Stream" was in quotes in the question, and the ask stated "Ideally I'd like to receive multiple response to periodically update a progress bar", a polling solution was viable, easy to implement, and lacked dependencies on third party software. I know it's not streaming, but the request used it as a verb not a technical requirement.

Comment: 7 years ago, streaming was accomplished by long polling. I made a streaming chat application back then - it streamed incoming messages. So no this wasn't streaming 7 years ago either.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the library "comet." It's implements what's known as "reverse AJAX." It'll allow you to send events from the server to the client easily.

The polling suggestion made just before mine, is also perfectly valid.