# Dynamic display multiple JSON responses while processing a file

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom-events

Let me try to explain my question:

I am trying to upload a scv file with 10k+ rows. Anyhow in these rows might happen some errors.

Is it even possible to be done to return JSON for each error that occurs while the file is still processing to be imported to a database?

//edit
ok here is my reading code

```
 if (($handle = fopen('main_class/kur/'.$fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 30000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;

        foreach ($data AS $columns=>$val){
            $data[$check->numberToColumnName($columns+1)]=$val;
            unset($data[$columns]);
        }

        $FormtedData = $check->FormatAllData($data);


        foreach ($FormtedData['vars'] AS $key=>$value){
            $column_type = $check->CheckType($value,$key);     

            switch ($column_type){
                case 'int' : $type=' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL ';
                    break;
                case 'float' : $type=' FLOAT NOT NULL ';
                    break;
                case 'TEXT' : $type=' TEXT NOT NULL ';
                    break;
                case 'varchar' : $type=' VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ';
                    break;

                default : ' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL ';
            }
            if ($row<3){
                $check->addColumnIfItDoesNotExist($key,$type); 
            }

            if ($column_type=='TEXT'){
                $PreviousType = $check->SingleColumnType($key);
                if ($PreviousType=='varchar(255)'){
                    $check->ChangeCoolumnType($key,$type);
                }    
            }                
        }

        $check->InsertValue($FormtedData['vars']);

        /*
        //$num = count($data);

        //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }*/

        $column++;

        if ($check->numberToColumnName($num+1)==$column){
            $column='A';
        }

        //end of while for each row    
    }
    fclose($handle);
    //end of open
}
```

and here is my uploader:

```
function createUploader(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
        action: '?func=FileUpload',
        debug: false,
        onProgress : function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
            // dunno what is this :D    
        },
        onComplete : function (a,b,json){
            $.each(eval(json), function(i, item) {
                console.log(i,'---',item,'<-');
            });
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Just about anything is possible. Post your CSV import code, and we can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "stream" json from server to client using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157792/how-to-stream-json-from-server-to-client-using-javascript)

Comment: Ok this is what I got, the reverse ajax is the thing i need i guess. 

But it looks a little bit hard with this uploader, if anyone can give me some help where i should put the javascript code that is listening and where should i put the json_encode in php i will be very greatful

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about IE < 9 compatibility you can use the JavaScript FileReader API.

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

You'd read the selected upload csv file using JavaScript and send 1 row per Ajax request to the PHP script. PHP would process the row and either return success or your error message.

Comment: if it was for me i wouldn't care for the IE but unfortunately it is a project i am working on ( it's not for me, ah this English of mine )