# How to send two responses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to create an application that accepts an uploaded photo, writes the photo, then uploads it to a backup server. I would like it to send to the browser a `JSON` response stating `processing: true` when it's uploading to the backup server, and then `success: true` when it successfully uploads to the backup server.

I know about `response.stream.write` in Rails, but when I use this, it sends one response with both of my `json` objects instead of two responses with one `json` object each. How do I do two separate responses? Do I need to request the page twice or is there a way for the page to send the request automatically?

Answer (score 0):

See this stackoverflow post [How to "stream" json from server to client using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157792/how-to-stream-json-from-server-to-client-using-javascript). It's about your problem and it was answered.